# Generic argument list

Tags: c#, list, generics, arguments

I have a method that has a generic argument and the code is as shown below :

```
public Result[] Compare(PropertyInfo property, T previous, T current)
{
    var type = previous.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(type);
    var instance = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);

    instance = previous //throws compile error obviously,
}
```

The generic argument, `previous` and `current` is a `List<string>` or any other type `List`.

The problem is that I cannot seem to use the previous variable value in this method. I cannot enumerate through the data or assign it to the list I created locally. Is there a way to get the data from these parameters ?

Need suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: Your parameter may be ``List<T>`` not ``T``

Comment: Are there any restrictions on T?

Comment: Are you missing a constraint? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx public class Test<T> where T : IEnumerable

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public Result[] Compare<T>(PropertyInfo property, T previous, T current)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things too complicated. Just use an argument of type `List<T>` or `IList<T>`. If you don't need the list's index, but need to add or remove elements, you can also type the argument as `ICollection<T>`. If you only need to enumerate the collection, type it as `IEnumerable<T>`. This allows you to pass a greater number of types to your method.

You can also simply create a new list with:

```
var newList = new List<T>();
```

and you can create a new instance of T with:

```
T item = new T();
```

However, you must include the `new` constraint for this generic type argument, if you want to do this:

```
public class MyClass<T> : where T : new
{
    ...
}
```

`T` must then have a default constructor, i.e. a constructor with an empty argument list.

---

However, it is not clear from your question, what you are trying to achieve.

Maybe you are simply looking for this:

```
var result = myList
    .Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Equals(someValue));
```

Or if the property to look for can be chosen dynamically

```
public IEnumerable<T> Filter(Func<T, object> getProperty, IEnumerable<T> coll,
    object value)
{
    return coll
        .Where(x => getProp(x).Equals(value));
}
```

Call it like this

```
var result = Filter(x => x.SomeProperty, myList, someValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If T is an IEnumerable, you can access its element using a `foreach` loop. This is allowed since the compiler knows for sure that the parameter `previous` is an instance of `IEnumerable`.

```
foreach (object dataItem in previous)
{
    DoSomething(dataItem);
}
```

Obviously, you may want to cast `dataItem` to whatever seems appropriate, but this is strongly specific to your context.

*Edit:* Alternatively, you can make the element type to your type parameter. So use `class Test<T>` without a where clause and define `previous` as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you put `T` as your parameter you have it as a single object. If you want it to be a list of Ts then you need to have it as `List<T>`.